# Snowflake-Databricks- Failing to connect snowflake from Databricks as incoming connection is blocked

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-databricks

I am trying to connect snowflake from Azure Databricks using below code

```
import snowflake.connector

# Connection parameters
account = 'account'
user = 'user'
password = 'password'
warehouse = 'warehouse'
database = 'database'
schema = 'schema'

# Establish a connection
con = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user=user,
    password=password,
    account=account,
    warehouse=warehouse,
    database=database,
    schema=schema
)

# Create a cursor object
cur = con.cursor()

# Execute a SELECT query on a table
table_name = 'table1'  # Replace with the actual table name
query = f"SELECT * FROM {table_name}"

cur.execute(query)

# Fetch the results
results = cur.fetchall()

# Process and print the results
for row in results:
    print(row)

# Close the cursor and connection
cur.close()
con.close()
```

But above connection to the snowflake failes with below error

```
Failed to connect to DB <snowflake-url>:443. Incoming request with IP/Token <databricks spark ip> is not allowed to access Snowflake
```

As checked the "databricks spark ip" is a dynamic one that changes in every launching of the cluster.
So how do we establish a stable connection between Databricks and Snowflake in this case? I believe I could whitelist Databricks-spark IP if it was static, but in this case, it's dynamic.
Any solution to this?

Comment: So do you have a network policy set up in Snowflake that is blocking the range of IP addresses that the Spark cluster can use? If so, then you’ll either need to change/drop the policy or get the cluster to use a fixed IP

Answer (score 1):

You can also reach out to databricks team as My understanding is that it will use the dynamic addresses from a certain pool of IP addresses. If this pool of ip addresses is provided by your cloud infrastructure team, you can also get the range of ip addresses from them to which databricks cluster is getting the ip's assigned and whitelist them on Snowflake end via the network policy.